# How to get absolute time using Moment JS and Unix timestamp

Tags: javascript, timezone, momentjs

On server I use protobuf (google.protobuf.Int64Value start/end), convert DateTime value from database to timestamp(in milliseconds) with mapper and send to client.

Оn client i use moment to convert timestamps to start/end dates and display dates on screen

1. When i test locally (the server and the client are on my machine, i.e. the timezone is the same, for example GMT + 3) - everything is displayed correctly. I am creating an event from 10 to 20 July:

**In base**:

```
start - 2022-07-10 00:00:00.0000000
end - 2022-07-20 23:59:59.9990000
```

**Timestamps**:

```
start - 1657400400000
end - 1658350799999
```

**Moments on client**:

```
start - Sun Jul 10 2022 00:00:00 GMT+0300
end - Wed Jul 20 2022 23:59:59 GMT+0300
```

**Display in event list**

```
7/10/22 - 7/20/22
```

2. Problems with displaying dates start if I use a server located in a different time zone or, for example, I change the location in the browser (let it be Tokyo, GMT+9):

**Moments on client**:

```
start - Sun Jul 10 2022 06:00:00 GMT+0900
end - Thu Jul 21 2022 05:59:59 GMT+0900
```

**Display in event list**

```
7/10/22 - 7/21/22
```

How can this problem be solved? I should see the same event start/end time no matter what timezone the server or client is in.

Comment: p.s.  If I send a datetime object to the client instead of a timestamp, then everything works correctly. When change the location in the browser, the time remains unchanged, only the time zone changes. Moment on client for Moscow, GMT+3   -   `end - Wed Jul 20 2022 23:59:59 GMT+0300`.  Moment on client for Tokyo, GMT+9   -   `end - Wed Jul 20 2022 23:59:59 GMT+0900`.  Тeed the same behavior when using timestamp.

Comment: Hi.  You haven't shown any code, so it's hard to answer your question directly.  Please read [*How do I ask a good question?*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [*How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), then edit your question to add supporting details.  Thanks.